# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_generate_attachment_metadata() @ wp-cron

Tags: plugins, php, wp-cron, cron

Devs

I have a WP-cronjob running that is supposed to import some pictures and set them as attachments for a specific post. But I'm apparently unable to do so while running it as a WP-cronjob - it works just fine when i run it on "init" for exampel. But as soon as i try to run it within a WP-cronjob it fails.

```
 register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'OA_FeedManager_activated' );
 function importpicture_activated()
 {
    if (! wp_next_scheduled( 'import_feed' ) ) 
    {
       wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'import' );
    }
 }

  add_action( 'import', 'call_import' );
  function call_import() 
  {
        //lots of code, where i get data from a XML feed, and creates a new post. no need to include it.           

        foreach($oDataXML->Media->Fotos->Foto as $key => $value)
        {
            $filename = wp_upload_dir()['path'].'/'.$oDataXML->SagsNr->__toString().'_'. $value->Checksum->__toString() . '.jpg';  
            $sPicture = $value->URL->__toString();
            copy($sPicture, $filename);
            $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $filename ), null );

            $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $attachment = array(
               'guid'           => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $filename ),
               'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
               'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $filename ) ),
               'post_content'   => '',
               'post_status'    => 'inherit'
            );
            $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $iPost_ID );
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );           
        }
  }
```

As I have been able to read, its because that the `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` function is not currently included when doing a `wp-cronjob`, and I should `require_once('wp-load.php')`.

But sadly I'm not able to require that while running a cron job (I tried both `wp-load.php` & `wp-includes/post.php`) - but neither does the trick.

So maybe there is a wise man on WPSE that can enlighten me how I'm suppose to get my WP-cronjob running correctly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some of what is usually admin side functionality is not included as part of the "main" wordpress bootstrap, files containing uploaded file manipulation functions are one of them and you need to explicitly include them by adding

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
```

into your `call_import` function.

Comment: @Fayaz, sorry for taking rep from you, was just easier to answer than to comment ;)

Comment: I wanted to delete my answer (after yours), but it has part of the solution as well, So I updated it instead :)

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your cronjob script (for example: `my-cron.php`), do this:

```
if ( ! defined('ABSPATH') ) {
    /** Set up WordPress environment */
    require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );
}
```

Then setup cron like this in your server:

```
5 * * * * wget -q -O - http://your-domain.com/my-cron.php
```

> **Note:** perhaps you were trying to run cron as PHP Command Line (CLI), that'll not work. You need to run cron as HTTP request (with `wget` or `curl`), as shown above.

For more information [read this official WordPress document](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-wp-cron-into-the-system-task-scheduler/#mac-os-x-and-linux).

### Update:

Based on newly added CODE, I can see this CODE is wrong:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'OA_FeedManager_activated' );
function importpicture_activated() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'import_feed' ) )  {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'import' );
    }
 }

 add_action( 'import', 'call_import' );
 function call_import() {
     // lots of code
 }
```

You checked `if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'import_feed' ) )` but you are scheduling `add_action( 'import', 'call_import' );`. For cron to work properly you must register the same action `import`. Also, your activation hook is `OA_FeedManager_activated`, make sure it runs `importpicture_activated` function. So the CODE should be like:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'OA_FeedManager_activated' );

function OA_FeedManager_activated() {
    importpicture_activated();
}

function importpicture_activated() {
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'import' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'import' );
    }
 }

 add_action( 'import', 'call_import' );
 function call_import() {
     // lots of code
 }
```

To check if your cron is registered properly, you may use the [control plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/). Also, activate [WP debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see what error your CODE is generating.

> ***Note:*** For undefined function `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` error [check Mark's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/261262/110572) answer.

Also, since you've scheduled the cron in plugin's activation hook, you must deactivate and then activate the plugin again if you change activation hook function. Using Crontrol Plugin, make sure there is not unnecessary cron registered in the backend.

Finally, check if in `wp-config.php` you have `define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true );`. You must remove it (if it is there) or set it to `false`, if you want WP cron to run on normal WP load. Otherwise, you'll need to set cron with OS crontab (like shown at the beginning of my answer.)

Comment: can i not just run it with WP's buildin cronjob?

Comment: @Jùrgen, run what? your question lack details on what is it actually that you are doing and from the way it is written it reads like you are using the OS cron

Comment: @Mark Kaplun actually I'm saying multiple places (even in the title, that we are talking about a wp-cronjob). But i have no editted my question, so it says WP-conjob everywhere :)

Comment: @Jùrgen than why do you try to load wordpress? this is not how wordpress cron works. If you try to use the wordpress cron, you are doing it totally wrong

Comment: @Mark Kaplun what do you mean try to load wordpress? i have setup a WP-cronjob to do some download some pictures (if any new) and add them to the related posts. I'm not trying to load anything, but i expect a simple wordpress function works, when I'm running a WP-cronjob

Comment: @Fayaz i have added the part of the code, but the problem is not the code - the code is running exactly as its supposed to - as long as I'm not calling it from within a WP-cronjob.
The problem arises because i get the error: "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_generate_attachment_metadata()"

Comment: fixed it, still the same problem, i can run the wp-cron with croncontrol - no problems. The problem is that i get a Call to undefined function wp_generate_attachment_metadata()